# Can't remember the name of a Windows feature/program

Tags: windows

What is the name of the Windows program or feature that pops up the first time a user attempts to run a program under Windows 7 and later and asks the user if it is OK to run the program? I'm drawing a blank.

Is there something similar for Windows XP?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the name of the Windows program or feature that pops up the first time a user attempts to run a program under Windows 7 and later and asks the user if it is OK to run the program?

It isn't a program, but a kernel feature called User Account Control (UAC), and it only exists in Windows Vista and newer.

> Is there something similar for Windows XP?

No

Comment: [UAC was introduced in Vista](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/922708/how-to-use-user-account-control-uac-in-windows-vista)